# Swift - Segue to a specific view if conditions met

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tab bar with an item that leads to a navigation controller, which has a list of the user's friends. However, while an anonymous user should be able to browse the app, I only want logged in users to be able to view the friend list, since only then will they have friends. I'm using Parse as a backend, so I can test `PFUser.currentUser()`, but I have no idea how to tell the navigation controller to segue to a VC that prompts the user to log in/sign up if they aren't already. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've implemented the suggested solution in the tab bar controller class, and looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarController?.delegate = self
}

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController == FriendsTableViewController() {
        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            println("there is a logged in user")
            return true
        } else {
            let authVC:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("auth") as UIViewController
            presentViewController(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            println("attempted to present auth vc")
            return false
        }
    } else {
        println("not friends table vc")
        return true
    }
}
```

However, nothing is outputted when I select the friends bar item. What am I missing?

Edit: Resolved. This is the code for viewWillAppear in the view controller for the friends vc:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
        var login = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("auth") as AuthenticationVC
        self.presentViewController(login, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `tabBarController.delegate` to `self`? Also, I would return `true` in your _not friends table vc_ `else` statement because you would still want to be able to switch to other views, unless you have other reasons for returning `false`.

Comment: The problem is still there.

Comment: The delegate is supposed to be set outside the method call. If you're using storyboard, you can drag the `delegate` property in the connection inspector to your view controller. If you're doing it through code, you can set the delegate in your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: There's still no output. When exactly is tabBarController called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually accomplish this, and this applies to apps both with and without tab bars, is to have some kind of requires authentication flag in the destination view controller, and if the user isn't logged in, present the login screen modally.

e.g. inside the friends list view controller (assuming using storyboard but it doesn't make a big difference):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
        var login = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController
        //set properties of login 
        self.presentViewController(login, animated: YES)
    }
}
```

(or use performSegue)

IMHO the modal presentation style is more appropriate here, since it's like a tangent from the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate method for `UITabBarControllerDelegate` that would work. You can do a check using the `viewController` variable provided by the delegate.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController == FriendListViewController() {
        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            return true
        }
        else {
            // Prompt login/signup
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would be the best place to put this code? As far as I'm aware, you can't make an outlet to a UI element from any arbitrary file. Thanks.

Comment: I totally missed the tab bar part of your question. But the idea would still work. The code can go in `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` which is a method in `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, but instead of calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`, you just return `true` if user is logged in and return `false` if user is __not__ logged in. I've updated the answer with the delegate method.